# What is the correct format for my datetime object in python?

Tags: python, datetime

I'm trying to turn a string into a datetime object, however, I don't know what format I should use.
No matter what I try I get this error: time data '2022-02-19 16:58:39.937000' does not match format <"the format I input">. Do you know what format I have to use for this date: "2022-02-19 16:58:39.937000"?

Comment: What _is_ the format you input? That might help illustrate your specific misunderstanding. Otherwise just read https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To  turn a string into a datetime object you need to do this:

```py
import datetime

origin = '2022-02-19 16:58:39.937000'

time_converted= datetime.datetime.strptime(origin, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
print(type(time_converted))

<class 'datetime.datetime'>
```

Your problem must be the separation between the formatting.